# bug width of jqvmap with ionic

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building a mobile app that has only the jqvmap plugin on the main page but this weird bug keeps happening, sometimes the map is displayed correctly but sometimes it's not (image bellow).

here's my code :

```
<ion-view title="Trouver du fret" style="background-color: #F7F7F7">

    <div class="MapContainer" style="width:100%;padding-top: 60px;" >

         <label class = "item item-input item-select">
           <div class = "input-label" style="white-space: normal;">
            Choisissez votre région
           </div>

            <select ng-model="selectedRegion" ng-change="gotoRegion(selectedRegion)">
                <option value="0"> --  </option>
                <option ng-repeat="reg in allRegions" value="{{reg.Region.id}}">
                    {{reg.Region.name}}
                </option>
            </select>
         </label>
         <div class="card">
            <div class="item item-text-wrap" id="francemap" style=" height: 450px;"></div>
         </div>  
    </div>
</ion-view>
```

and the function that i use to draw the map is launched on the `'$ionicView.loaded'` event :

```
$('#francemap').vectorMap({
            map: 'france_fr',
            hoverOpacity: 0.5,
            hoverColor: "#0DC12D",
            backgroundColor: "#fff"  , //  "#F7F7F7",
            color: "#27ae60",
            borderColor: "#000000",
            selectedColor: "#0DC12D",
            enableZoom: false,
            showTooltip: true,
            onResize: function (element, width, height) {
                console.log('Map Size: ' +  width + 'x' +  height);
              },
            onRegionClick: $scope.regionClick
        });
```

[image: So what i am supposed to have is the picture on the right but i am getting the map cropped as shown in the picture on the left]

Comment: You need to explain what the "bug" is.

Comment: @theblindprophet the bug is as shown in the picture, the map is cropped and is getting out of the screen, i'm using the french map

Comment: The bug is not clear to other users, you need to present what the expected view looks like compared to the "bug".

Comment: @theblindprophet thanks for the notice, i've updated my post i hope my issue is clear now

Comment: Perfect. Good layout for the question.